# CSS background gradient is not completely above the background image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, gradient

I need a gradient over a background image. Unfortunately, the gradient is not completely over the image, which then leads to a kind of line through the edge of the image, which sticks out on the side. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Here you can try: [Tailwind-Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZQV2HD1Wyt)

*Part of the image*

```
    <div class="w-3/5 absolute right-0" style="height: 40rem; background: linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0, 0, 0, .01) 1%, rgb(255, 255, 255, 1) ), url({{ bigImageRight.bild.one().getUrl() }}); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
```

*Complete Code (Tailwind CSS)*

```
<div class="mt-24">
  <div class="">
    <div
      class="w-3/5 absolute right-0"
      style="
  height: 40rem;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg,
rgba(0, 0, 0, .01) 1%, rgb(255, 255, 255, 1) ), url({{ bigImageRight.bild.one().getUrl() }}); background-size: cover;
background-position: center;"></div>

    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto">

      <div class="relative max-w-4xl px-8 z-30 flex flex-row flex-wrap right-0 items-center" style="height:40rem;">
        <div class="max-w-7xl">
        <p class="font-bold text-blue-600 text-xl">{{ bigImageRight.untertitel }}</p>
        <h4 class="text-4xl text-gray-800 font-light pb-8">{{ bigImageRight.titel }}</h4>
        <div class="text-lg text-gray-800">
          {{ bigImageRight.text }}
        </div>

        <div class="mt-8">

        {% if bigImageRight.buttonText %}
        <a href="{{ bigImageRight.buttonVerlinkung }}" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500">
          {{ bigImageRight.buttonText }}
          <svg class="-mr-1 ml-2 h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewbox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7"/>
          </svg>
        </a>
      {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: Line near gradient]

However, when I resize my browser windows, every now and then the dash disappears.

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/egV5NEzRBt here is your code. what the problem with it ?

Comment: Does it fix your problem if you adjust your gradient start position, e.g. `linear-gradient(rgba(43, 43, 43, .0) -10px, rgba(29, 29, 29, .8) 100% )`? The markup you provided doesn't match your image.

Comment: The problem is that through the angle the progression should go from left to right. The image should first be white and then become colored

Comment: @GeorgeSun sorry I have copied the wrong code... Now it's the correct one :)

Comment: I have build an example for you: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZQV2HD1Wyt

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a possible bug with the way `background-size` `cover` is rendered for fractional pixel width elements.

As an alternative, you could use a pseudo `::before` element instead of `background-image` with `linear-gradient`.

i.e.

```
.hero::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .01) 1%, rgb(255, 255, 255));
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Example [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/OgyTZ0sORr).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution:

```
<div
      class="w-3/5 absolute right-0"
      style="background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 10vw, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)),
    url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1632310453712-1d09e6b50f05?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80');
    width: 80%;
    height: 40rem;
    background-size: cover;"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).